# AngularJS: Temporarily disable data binding.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to temporarily disable data binding in AngularJS. I have a list `items` which I render using `ng-repeat`. I want to do some list operations on `items`, while data-binding is temporarily disabled, so that the intermediary changes are not reflected on the page thereby slowing it down. Instead I want to perform the operations on the list and thereafter re-enable data binding.

Comment: You could always perform these list operations on a copy of the `items` if that is feasible for your situation. More context would help.

Comment: The model already only updates after the code that does the manipulation has run. You may need to describe how the manipulation works to get anything more useful.

Answer (score 3):

```
var items = angular.copy($scope.items);
..
..
..
/* perform operations over items */
..
..
..
$scope.items = angular.copy(items);
```